# Asigna ancho a celda de tabla con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular

Buen día, me pueden colaborar por favor, tengo una tabla con booststrap, tengo dos columnas que pueden recibir hasta 500 caracteres peno quiero que se desborden, sino que cuando llegue al ancho de la columna el texto se alinee verticalmente y que este se mantenga cuando se hace la paginación.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class=" table-responsive"> 
    <!-- col testeo-scroll -->
    <table class="table align-middle table-striped  ">
      <thead>
        <tr class="bg-success align-bottom">
          <td class="thInicial">Nombre</td>
          <td style="width: 35% !important;">Valor</td>
          <td style="width: 35% !important;">Descripción</td>
          <td>Estado</td>
          <td class="thFinal">Editar</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="bodyTableParametros">
        <tr *ngFor="let elemento of parametro_test | slice:desde:hasta">
          <td class="tdInicial">{{elemento.nombre}}</td>
          <td style="width: 100px !important;">{{elemento.valor}}</td>
          <td style="width: 100px !important;">{{elemento.descripcion}}</td>
          <td>{{elemento.estado == true ? 'Habilitado' : 'Deshabilitado'}}</td>
          <td class="tdFinal">
            <button style="color: #00993E;" mat-icon-button aria-label="remove"
              (click)='formulario("editar", elemento.id)'>
              <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [length]="parametro_test.length" [pageSize]="pageSize" (page)="cambiarPagina($event)"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar **[ngClass]** para asignar clases usando logica.

En el Template:

```
<td [ngClass]="{ elemento.nombre.length > 500 ? 'align-special': 'align-normal' }">{{elemento.nombre}}</td>
```

En el archivo de estilos css/scss:

```
.align-normal: { text-align: center };
.align-special: { text-align: left };
```